# Error on django - .save() function

Tags: python, django

```
class Member(models.Model):# member db table
    userID      = models.CharField(max_length=80,primary_key=True) #user id 
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=32)# password
    nickname    = models.CharField(max_length=100)# user nickname
    penalty     = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=10,default=0,null=True)
    participation=models.ForeignKey('Room',default=None,blank=True,null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userID

def doJoin(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        # check validation
        userID = request.POST['userID']
        userNickname = request.POST['nickname']
        if (checkID(userID) == False) and (checkNickname(userNickname) == False) :
            #save to the database
            newUser = Member()
            newUser.userID = userID
            newUser.nickname = userNickname
            newUser.password = request.POST['password']
            print newUser.userID , newUser.nickname , newUser.password , newUser.penalty , newUser.participation
            newUser.save() #<------------error line!!!!

            return HttpResponse('true')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('false')
    else:
        HttpResponse('false')
```

line about 8

In function `doJoin`:

```
newUser.save() # <--- error... so sad...
```

What should I do? Help me please.

What's wrong in this source?

Comment: What is the error, Can u add the error details also in your question?

Comment: newUser.save() under the print newUser.userID .....

Comment: please ignore 'def __unicode__(self)' function

Comment: @user1590129: But what error does it give? Not just where it gives the error.

Comment: i don't know exactly ...
just...
10/Aug/2012 06:39:59] "POST /doJoin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10511
there is this message on my screen

Comment: http://goo.gl/S7Cdj <- this is my git repository please help me

Comment: Find a stack trace. We're not here to debug your entire app

Comment: +1 this is a fine question, OP (who is obviously New Here) just needs to turn on debugging, get a stack trace and post it. Don't be hatin'

Comment: (NB, pirtaja, set `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`, go to whichever URL you've specified for `doJoin()`, click "Switch to copy and paste view" and .. err .. copy and paste into your question. If you don't do this, nobody can help you, and people will keep down-voting)

Comment: @supervacuo: Downvote = "This question does not show any research effort. It is unclear or not useful." That is the definition of "I got  an error" questions with no traceback. If the OP posts the traceback, then those who downvoted can always reverse their vote, but it deserves a downvote until it's corrected.

Comment: Fair point, just saying it might be a little unwelcoming to somone who's just starting out.

Comment: problem is 'syncdb with south'

thx every one~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have debugging turned off? If you're getting a 500 and you have debugging turned on, you'll get a stack trace with the exception.

What are `checkID()` and `checkNickname()` doing? If those are performing some sort of validation, you really should be doing that in a form class instead of in the view. I also wouldn't be pulling values directly out of the `request.POST` to populate your model. I would highly recommend retrieving those values from a form's `cleaned_data` dictionary.